# Compile error with "cin >> a >> b" with intel c++ compile in release version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, intel

When I use the intel C++ compiler with VS2015 to compile a release version, it will fail. But when I compile a debug version, it work. I can't understand what happen. It the configure have some wrong? The error list is in below. How can I do?

--edit--

Today I compare the configure between the debug version and the release version in each option, I finally find if I set **interprocedural optimization** to no or single-file(/Qip), it works. But if i set the **interprocedural optimization** to Multi-File(/Qipo), it doesn't work. Besides, I can't find the iostream in the intel C++ compiler include path, the project seem like to use the library in VC++, it that the reason why I can't compile? How can I solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

> warn #11021    unresolved __imp_?_Src@?3??_Getffld@?$num_get@DV?$istreambuf_iterator@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@std@@ABAHPADAAV?$istreambuf_iterator@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@3@1AAVios_base@3@PAH@Z@4QBDB   test        1
>
> error  #11023  Not all components required for linking are present on command line test        1

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    while (cin >> a >> b)
    cout << a << ' ' << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it compiles a release version if you remove this line? Maybe, the problem is not in `cin >> a >> b` line.

Comment: _"when I compile a debug version"_ This is wildly insufficient information about your environment and built parameters.

Comment: I am sure that it compiles a release version when i remve this line. And I use the defult configure in VS2015 for the debug version and release version.

Comment: Try creating a new empty project and copying in your source files.

Comment: Sounds as if the linker can’t find the right version of a library?

Comment: I have tried to copy the source files to a new empty project and test for each function. Finally I find that if I remove cin>>a>>b, the project can be built. So I write this code to test and this code can't be compiled too.

Comment: I think the linker use the VC++ library instread of the intel C++ library, but I can find the iostream.h in the intel C++ compiler..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: This is a linker error - you linking against one set of libraries in debug and something completely different in release (not just the release version of the same library). Compare the linker options and link libraries and search for libraries out of place or missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I asking in the intel developer zone. They tell me the issue is ONLY reproducible with /MD and /Qipo used together, so I may use /MT to work around it. And when I use /MT, it works.